# Selecting row ids that don't match row ids of a sub match

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: Sentence and WordIndex.

**Sentence:**
id,
text,
wordId

**WordIndex:**
id,
word,
sentenceId

### Scenario:

*Example:*
Sentence Table
1, "I jumped over the dog", [1,2,3,4,5]
2, "I tripped over the cat", [6,7,8,9,10]

WordIndex Table
1, "i", 1
2, "jumped", 1
3, "over", 1
4, "the", 1
5, "dog", 1
6, "i", 2
7, "tripped", 2
8, "over", 2
9, "the", 2
10, "cat", 2

I want to find all sentences that exclusively consist of any of the following words: "i", "jumped", "over", "the", "dog", "cat".
If I just search the index for those words, Sentence #2 will be returned, which should not be included.
My thought is to find the rows in the WordIndex that don't match the target words. That result consists of all the SentenceId's I don't want and none that I do. Then, get the ids of the sentences that aren't in that result.

The problem is, I'm very new to MySQL, and have two questions.
1) Does that seem like the most efficient way to get the desired result? I need this to scale well (millions of indices and thousands of target/allowed words). 
2) How would I translate that solution into a SQL statement?

Comment: You ought to look into [full text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html).

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I read through the various full text search options. It doesn't look like it addresses my scenario because I'm not looking for certain words that are or are not present in rows. I'm looking for rows that only contain words from an array of words, but none of those words are specifically required.

Comment: for highly relational data, consider [mongodb](http://www.mongodb.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question. The following query (using Doctrine Query Language) will retrieve the sentences that only contain words from an array of given words.

```
$search = "w.text != 'WORD' AND w.text != 'WORD'...";
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$query = $em->createQuery("
    SELECT s FROM BundleName:Sentence s 
    WHERE s.id NOT IN 
    (SELECT t.id FROM BundleName:Sentence t 
    JOIN t.words w WHERE ".$search.")
");
```

I'm not sure if this is efficient, but it seems to work.